# Beginning to use arrays in java, having hard time accessing certain info

Tags: java, constructor

I am a very new student to java, and we are beginning to use arrays.  I have an assignment I have been working on which is troubling me (hopefully only in a syntactic sense).  I have a class in which I have written various sorting methods.  I then have another class which I have declared two final int arrays used in the sorting methods (one for sales ranges, and one for the commission rate associated to the sales ranges).  I am to then create a no arg constructor which reads two strings from a file (a salesperson's ID number and name - both which have to be Strings). I have to make three arrays in said constructor: one for the sales ID's, on for the associate names, and one for total commissions.  I then have to create a method to accumulate the individual sales persons total commissions. I hope this makes some sense, without posting the three pages of directions I have.

My question is simply (for you guys) this:  I have the class with the sorting methods written, I have the no arg constructor written, I have most of the 'commission tally' method written.  How the hell do I access the commissions array inside of the constructor from the 'commission tally' method so I can actually begin to populate that array?

Comment: can we see the code where you have the arrays,and the code where you want to access them?

Comment: no way to understand that. Show us the code and pinpoint the location you want to access the said array.

Answer (score 1):

For a method to access variables in the constructor, the variable needs to be set in a field in the class.

```
public class Foo {
    private String[] array;
    public Foo() {
        array = new String[] {"some", "stuff"};
    }
    public void method() {
       System.out.println("I can access "+array[0]+" "+array[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh damn,what a boob.  Thanks for reinforcing that for me.